# Get rows back from a dropped table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one problem. I dropped a table in sqldeveloper and used flashback statement to get it back, but i also want to get the rows back. Is this possible?

Comment: ? The flashback should "restore" the table with the data (rows) it had right before it was dropped. Did you (or somebody or an application) delete rows from the table, or truncate, before dropping the table?

Comment: Did you just drop the table or did you also purge it from Oracle's recycle bin? If it is in the recycle bin then you should be able to find it through SQL developer's connection pane and then right-click and select "Flashback to Before Drop..." and it will bring back the table with all the data from before the drop.

Comment: @MT0 - The OP said he already got the table back with flashback, so it wasn't purged from the recycle bin (if I understand how that works - it is entirely possible that I don't).